# realocação dinâmica - array de struct

Tags: c, array, struct, malloc

Preciso fazer um exercício em que o código aloque a memória conforme necessário, porém preciso realocar uma array de struct, só que acabei travando nessa parte.

Minha Struct é:

```
typedef struct{
    char nome[100];
    char endereco[100];
    int numero;
    char telefone[11];
    char sexo;
    char cpf[11];
    data nascimento;
    double saldo;
}cliente;
```

Criei dentro da função `main()` o ponteiro que vai receber o endereço da minha struct.

```
cliente *cliente;
```

Aloquei a memória para apenas 1 posição da minha struct

```
cliente = malloc(sizeof(cliente));
```

Durante a execução do meu código, eu realoco a memória para receber mais um "cliente", utilizando

```
cliente = (struct cliente*) realloc(cliente, tam*sizeof(cliente));
```

porém quando eu utilizo a função para mostrar os clientes cadastrados, todos aparecem com lixo de memória nas variáveis, menos o último, o que estou fazendo de errado?

Comment: Apenas como nota, você pode usar sempre `realloc`, desde que na primeira vez passe o ponteiro `cliente` com `NULL`. Dessa forma fica mais simples de gerir pois não tem de individualizar o primeiro caso. Ainda assim, o erro provavelmente estará no código que não está a mostrar, pois o que mostrou até agora parece bem, assumindo que ele foi executado na ordem certa.

Answer (score 0):

Não há nada de errado em encontrar lixo após o `realloc()` porque esta função não inicializa o espaço de memória RAM alocado.

Caso prefira, veja `calloc()`.

Answer (score -1):

O que ocorreu foi que quando usou o `realloc` como gerenciamento de memória em tempo de execução, não criou uma nova área de memória, mas sim alterou o tamanho. Se não estivesse definido o tamanho, teria ocorrido um retorno de um ponteiro NULL.

Deveria ter passado o tamanho da struct, no entanto, foi passado um ponteiro.

```
cliente = malloc(sizeof(cliente));
```

Tamanho será o número de instâncias da struct cliente (*correção*)

```
cliente = malloc(sizeof(cliente) * tamanho);
```

E nessa parte, um cast para struct `cliente *` foi implementado. Se pararmos para entender, cliente já era um ponteiro para a struct e, complementando, já havia alocado espaço para uma instância da struct cliente

```
cliente = (struct cliente*) realloc(cliente, tam*sizeof(cliente));
```

(*correção*)

```
clientes = (cliente*) realloc(clientes, tam * sizeof(cliente));
```

código completo:

```
  typedef struct{
    char nome[100];
    char endereco[100];
    (...continua)
} cliente;

int main() {
    int tamanho = 1;
    cliente *clientes = (cliente*) malloc(tamanho * sizeof(cliente));
    if (clientes == NULL) {
        printf("nao foi alocado memoria.");
        return 1;
    }

    
    strcpy(clientes[0].nome, "Luffy");
    (...continua)

    // realocar 
    tamanho++;
    clientes = (cliente*) realloc(clientes, tamanho * sizeof(cliente));
    if (clientes == NULL) {
        printf("nao foi realocado.");
        return 1;
    }

    
    strcpy(clientes[1].nome, "Katakuri");
    (...continua)
        
    for (int i = 0; i < tamanho; i++) {
        printf("Nome ::..  %s  \n", clientes[i].nome);
        
    }

    // liberar a memoria  
    free(clientes);
    return 0;
}
```

Havia  alocado espaço para apenas um cliente ou seja uma instância da `struct` cliente e depois tentou realocar memória para receber mais clientes  multiplicando `sizeof(cliente`)  por `tam`  que resultou em bytes maiores do que precisava